# Terminate line for only one column of each row while writing csv

Tags: python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

I have list of lists as:

```
list = [["1","this is first note.[CR][LF] This is next line","type1"], ["2","this is second note[CR][LF]. This is next line","type2"]]
```

I tried to write csv as:

```
writer = open('test.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(writer, delimiter=";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, )
for row in rows:
        if len(row) > 0:
            row[1] = str(row[1]).replace("[CR]", "\r").replace("[LF]", "\n")
            logging.info("writing rows into csv " + str(count))
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
writer.close()
```

I expected the following result:

```
|-----------|---------------------------|-------|
|   id      |     note                  |type   |
|-----------|---------------------------|-------|
|    1      |    this is the first note.|       |
|           |      this is next line    |type1  |
|           |                           |       |
|-----------|---------------------------|-------|
```

But I got following result:

```
|--------------------|---------------------------|-------|
|   id               |     note                  |type   |
|--------------------|---------------------------|-------|
|    1               |    this is the first note.|       |
|this is next line   |          type1            |       |
|                    |                           |       |
|--------------------|---------------------------|-------|
```

Is it possible to write csv as expected in fisrt table? As i am new to python and csv please can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Given your data such as:

`listt = [["1","this is first note.[CR][LF] This is next line","type1"], ["2","this is second note[CR][LF]. This is next line","type2"]]`

We can use the `pandas` library to conveniently write to csv:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(listt, columns=["id", "note", "type"]) #Instantiate a dataframe

df["note"] = df.note.str.replace("\[CR\]", "\r").str.replace("\[LF\]", "\n") #Replace the strings you want

df.to_csv("yourfilename.csv")
```

You would have to check if the newline is then properly parsed by your CSV reading program but the newline characters should be there now.